# can't run both phpmyadmin and rails server on cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, cloud9

I am working on a **rails** project on *cloud9* and I followed [this tutorial to install  PhPmyadmin](https://c9.io/blog/phpmyadmin/).

The problem is that I can't  run at the same time a rails server and a php my admin server since they both seem to use the same Port.
To launch my rails server, I use `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`.

Here is the error I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:205:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:8080 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is just another PHP application, so it doesn't listen on a port. You should instead check your webserver configuration to see what port it is on. Most webservers tend to default to port 80, though, so it might be some other process.

You can use `netstat -tulpn | grep 8080` to find what's using that port and modify either your Rails configuration or the other process to use a different port.